# How do I change the "junk" setting on Gmail?

Tags: gmail-filters

How do I stop Gmail from automatically labeling ALL my incoming mail as "junk"?

Comment: Gmail doesn't mark messages as "junk". If you don't actually mean "spam", then it's something else that's doing it. Either a rogue filter put in by someone who hacked your account or a third-party tool that you've given access to.